# TkInter app going periodically unresponsive

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a TkInter (Python 2.7) app that needs to do a long-running operation.  I am using the `threading` module to spin off this operation onto its own thread, but I'm still experiencing intermittent bouts of unresponsiveness in my UI as the operation is proceeding.

It seems that during times when the long-running operation is doing intense I/O, the UI becomes unresponsive, then when the intense I/O subsides, the UI frees up again, even though I only start the thread once.  Here is the code where I'm starting the thread:

```
from threading import Thread
# ...
self.thread = Thread(target=getStats, args=(self.components, self.queue))
self.thread.start()
```

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like your long-running process is CPU bound. Threading is best for IO bound. multiprocessing is better for CPU bound applications.

Comment: I think my process is I/O bound

Comment: I know you think that but I suspect you are wrong. Look at your system monitor. Does one of the processors go to 100% when the long-running process is "doing intense I/O"? Remember threading can only use one processor, so you have to look at the system monitor that shows your processors individually.

Comment: It was doing I/O but it was using the `os` python module to do it.  So while it was waiting for the I/O to complete, there was python bytecode waiting.  That is all I can think of, because it really was not CPU bound.  Anyway, switching from `threading` to `multiprocessing` solved my issue.  I hardly had to change the code at all!  I even was able to keep using a queue for communication (`multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `Queue.Queue`)